# Using Custom Permissions to restrict picklist values to specific users

Tags: picklist, permissions, validation-rule, permission-sets, custom-permission

*My goal:*
Using Validation Rules and Custom Permissions to restrict accessibility of specific values seen in the Account Type picklist to be available only to specific users.

I have the custom permission and permission set created, but am having trouble with the syntax of my Validation Rule for that picklist (account, type).

Here is what I have so far:

```
AND(
NOT ($Permission.Can_Set_Account_Type) 
OR(
ISPICKVAL(Type,"Partner"), 
ISPICKVAL(Type, "Partner Customer"), 
ISPICKVAL(Type, "Direct Customer") 
) 
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Figured it out...  Here is the syntax that I ended up using:

AND( 
NOT($Permission.Can_Set_Account_Type), 

OR( 
ISPICKVAL(Type,"Partner"), 
ISPICKVAL(Type, "Partner Customer"), 
ISPICKVAL(Type, "Direct Customer") 
) 
)

Comment: You may like to add your findings as an answer so that the question is marked as resolved.